# detox error minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs, detox

I have follow all the steps for install detox on my app and i read that detox accept minsdkVersion >= 18 , and my project runs minsdkVersion = 19 . I tried everything eve this guide for solving errors [link to the detox doc](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/troubleshooting/building-the-app/#problem-minsdkversion-mistmatch) but always this error showed up when i biuld the app on release and degub (yarn detox build --configuration android.emu.debug):

Error:
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.wix:detox:20.13.1] /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/f152bf0c894bece89167cc89d4b2917b/jetified-detox-20.13.1/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.wix.detox" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

My android/build gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.21"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 33
                buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    // afterEvaluate {
    //     if (it.hasProperty('android')){
    //         android {
    //             defaultConfig {
    //                 minSdkVersion 21
    //             }
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        maven {url("$rootDir/../node_modules/detox/Detox-android")}
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
    }
}

wrapper{
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}

project.ext {
    excludeAppGlideModule = true
}
```